# Is there a way to create a UNIQUE constraint on relationships in Neo

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In Neo4J it is possible to create a UNIQUE constraints on nodes like this:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (book:Book) ASSERT book.isbn IS UNIQUE
```

Is it possible to do the same with relationships.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If necessary, you can work around the lack of uniqueness constraint support for relationship types by "reifying" the relationships as nodes.

For example, instead of using this data model (where `:BORROWS(id)` must be unique, which is not supported):

```
(:Person)-[:BORROWS {id: 123}]->(:Book)
```

you can use something like this (where `:Borrowing(id)` must be unique, which is supported):

```
(:Person)-[:PERFORMS]->(:Borrowing {id: 123})-[:ON]->(:Book)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to apply unique constraints on relationships out of the box.